# Visual studio online continuous deployment to Azure SQL fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-devops

I have a WebSite that i have continuous deployment to Azure. I use Azure SQL as database. When I commit my changes to git source control on [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx) it automatically starts a build. This build fails with the below error message

> Cannot connect to the database 'xxxx.Models.Db'.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.
>   Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'data
>   source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=xxxx.Models.Db;integrated
>   security=True;application name=EntityFramework' cannot be created.
>   Failed to connect to server . Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake
>   acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed
>   or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent
>   while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=38386; handshake=182;

I have no connectionstring to any LocalDb. dbFullSql is totally unknown to me. Only database connection string I have is to the SQL Azure directly. Any ideas what this problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue in how Entity Framework is deploying the database.

The dbFullSql web deploy method is a legacy method and no longer recommended. Have a look at either a code first of dbDacFx deployment method instead.  See the docs on [EF deployment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction) for more information.

Comment: I don't understand this. I do use EF with code first migrations. Since i don't publish it directly to Azure, but commit to source control on Visual Studio Online, I'm unable to check any execute code first migrations that I would do otherwise. Can I turn off database deployment when VSO pushes the build to Azure?